# Java - "Cannot Find Symbol" error when calling Arrays.copyOfRange

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
public class DriverExam
{
    private String[] answers = {"B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"};
    private String[] input_validation = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    private String[] student_answers = new String[20];
    private int[] missed = new int[20];
    private int[] copy_missed;
    private boolean pass=true;
    private int number_missed = 0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;

    private String input()
    {
        input = kb.nextLine();
        while(!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")||input.equalsIgnoreCase("B")||input.equalsIgnoreCase("C")||input.equalsIgnoreCase("D")))
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter either A, B, C or D: ");
            input = kb.nextLine();
        }
        return input;
    }

    public boolean passed(String[] student_answers)
    {
        int v=0;

        for(int i=0; i<answers.length; i++)
        {
            if(!(answers[i].equalsIgnoreCase(student_answers[i])))
            {
                number_missed++;
                missed[v]=i;
                v++;

            }

        }
        if(number_missed>5)
        {
            pass=false;
        }
        return pass;
    }

    public String[] setStudentAnswers()
    {
        int question = 1;
        for(int i=0; i<student_answers.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the answer for question "+ question + ": ");
            student_answers[i]=input();
            question++;
        }

        return student_answers;
    }

    public int totalCorrect()
    {
        int correct = 20 - number_missed;
        return correct;
    }

    public int totalIncorrect()
    {
        return number_missed;
    }

    public int[] questionsMissed()
    {
        int[] copy_missed = Arrays.copyOfRange(missed, 0, number_missed);   
        return copy_missed;
    }

}
```

More specifically, in the method `questionsMissed()`, I keep getting `cannot find symbol` error when it comes to `Arrays.copyOfRange`.

I have checked the syntax, and I appear to be correct with `missed` being the `int[]`, `0` being the `int` and `number_missed` also being an int.

I'm stumped as to why it's not working.

Comment: What version of jdk are you using? copyOfRange is for 1.5+. Try using System.arraycopy() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int) If you are working with < 1.5

Comment: @OwerFlov I'm using jGrasp version 1.8.8_23. That should work, right? It says it's up to date.

Comment: @RyanStewart

DriverExam.java:83: cannot find symbol

symbol  : method copyOfRange(int[],int,int)

location: class java.util.Arrays

  int[] copy_missed = Arrays.copyOfRange(missed, 0, number_missed); 
                                          ^
1 error


(The arrow is right below the dot at Arrays.copyOfRange()

Comment: @gjvatsalya - from a command line run `javac -version` and add the version information printed out to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jGRASP home pages states that the latest version only requires JDK 1.5 to run, whereas [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) wasn't added until JDK 1.6. Witness the lack of any such method in the [docs for Arrays in 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). I don't know anything about jGRASP, but I'm guessing you're just running an old JDK under the hood because that error is very definitely because that method isn't available.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm running 1.5.
Do you by any chance know how to update it?

Comment: I actually got it fixed now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In JDK 1.5+ You should use

```
System.arraycopy()
```

Instead of

```
Arrays.copyOfRange()
```